# What is a good solution for efficiently loading a large number of Handlebar templates?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, mustache, templating

I have a scenario where I would like to load approximately 50 different Mustache/Handlebar templates to one page. The way I've typically gone about loading them is as follows:

```
function App(){

    this.templates = {
         template_one : {
               url : "path/to/template",
               template : ""
          },
          template_two : {
               url : "path/to/template",
               template : ""
          }
     }
}

App.prototype.getTemplates = function(){

      const keys = Object.keys(this.templates);

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           //Loop through each template and request it asynchronously
           keys.forEach((key, i) => {
               $.get(this.templates[key]['url'], template => {
                    this.templates[key]['template'] = template;
               }, "html").done(() => {
                    //When the last template has been retrieved, resolve the promise
                    if(i === keys.length - 1){
                         resolve();
                    }
               });
           });                
      });
}
```

This approach works just fine, however, conducting 50 separate async requests each time my page loads seems like a horrendous waste of network resources and is likely to be quite slow.

Is there a way to my front-end partials more efficiently?

**EDIT:**

As pointed out in the comments, a server-side solution is likely the correct way of accomplishing this. I'm currently using a php back-end, but am open to any process using gulp/grunt/node/etc.

I am still unsure of the process since the documentation for handlebars mentions loading individual files inside of `<script></script>` tags and referencing them via the script tag's id.

How would one go about a server-side build step for Handlebars/Mustache?

Comment: You could always add a build step to compile them in to a single file?

Comment: True, I was thinking something like that would work well. They'd all have to be wrapped in a <script></script> tag in order to identify them uniquely then right?

Comment: not with client side code alone there isn't

Comment: @charlietfl A server side solution is just fine!

Comment: not enough known for anyone to provide that

Comment: @charlietfl I added some additional detail. What information do you feel is necessary in order to provide advice on a server-side solution?

Comment: They wouldn't have to be in script tags if retrieved using ajax...they could be wrapped in `<div>` with class and you loop that class in response. in php could glob a directory and concatenate contents quite easily if that's how you wanted to manage it. Caching it would be best. or create a gulp/grunt/webpack build process to do same

Comment: With `jspm` and `systemJS` it'd be a trivial matter of bundling your app to a single file. Alternative to network resource waste would be to simply enable `http/2`. Enabling `http/2` would dramatically increase the loading / transfer time and you'd have to do nothing to your codebase.